# Return the partner of a tuple contained in list

Tags: python, function, data-structures

Suppose that there is a list:

```
x = [(3, 8), (2, 9), (1, 10), (0, 11)]
```

The elements of each tuple are unique (eg: the value `3` will no be present in any other tuple into `x`).

I want to define a function that return the partner of one tuple given the other partner. Eg:

```
>>> r = find_partner_of(2); print(r)
9
>>> r = find_partner_of(10); print(r)
1
```

My first attempt is make a `dict` like:

```
x = {3:8, 2:9, 1:10, 0:11, 8:3, 9:2, 10:1, 11:0}
```

But the data is huge, so I think that a simple function could be the best approach.

Thanks for the answers. So, a `dict` could be faster than a function like (?):

```
def find_partner(lst, value):
    for tpl in lst:
        if value in tpl:
            if tpl[0] == value:
                return tpl[1]
            else:
                return tpl[0]
```

Comment: Why not make the dict? It'll enable way faster lookup than searching through a list of tuples.

Comment: if the function will be called many many times, it may pay to build the dict from the list and use the dict to look up the partner. if it's used once or twice, i think it's simpler just to scan the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a dictionary is designed for exactly this purpose.  First create the dictionary in the "forward" direction, and then add the "backward"

```
partner = {item[0]: item[1] for item in x}
partner.update( {item[1]: item[0] for item in x} )
```

Now, your function is merely a dict lookup.  Here's how **partner** looks after each step:

```
{0: 11, 1: 10, 2: 9, 3: 8}
{0: 11, 1: 10, 2: 9, 3: 8, 8: 3, 9: 2, 10: 1, 11: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the dict, but if you really want the function:

```
def find_partner_of(n):
    global x
    for p in x:
        if p[0] == n: return p[1]
        if p[1] == n: return p[0]
```